# RouteAttribute not working for just one case

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.7.2

Why doesn't Route1 work (returning a 404 error) even if I omit Route2 and Route3?

```
public class IntegrationController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/integration/nfse")]
    public IHttpActionResult Route1()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/integration/nfse/{code}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Route2(string code)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/v1/integration/nfse")]
    public IHttpActionResult Route3()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new CustomExceptionLogger());

    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(UnityConfig.Configuracoes);

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, changes to routes might not take effect until the server is restarted. Have you tried to restart?

Comment: Yes, restart the machine and nothing.